# Looping through a string to delete certain characters

Tags: java, string

I'm looping through lines of text and from those individual lines I am looping and checking each character to check for Brackets. I want to delete each occurrence of a Closing bracket. For the most part it does work, but the very last Bracket for some reason gets missed and I have tried everything I could think of to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
public void moveClosedBrackets(){
    closedBrackets.clear();
    text = "";
    for (int count = 0; count < inputArray.size(); count++){
        text = inputArray.get(count);
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder(text);
        //System.out.println(newText.length());
        for(int count2 = 0; count2 < newText.length(); count2++){
            if(newText.charAt(count2) == '}'){
                newText = newText.deleteCharAt(count2);
                System.out.println(count2);
                inputArray.set(count, newText.toString());
                //inputArray.add(count = count +1, "}");
                closedBrackets.add(count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your entire script could be replaced with `text.replaceAll("\\}", "")`.

Comment: I wish I could, but I need to log how many Brackets I have in the string so if there are more after that one, then I would be getting incorrect results. I am keeping a counter of them.

Comment: Then all you'll need to do is subtract the length of the string after @TimBiegeleisen 's replacement from the original length: 2 lines of code instead of one.

Comment: @Gina, if you do not want use replaceAll, take a look at newText.length which is changed after deleting char

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
int length = text.length();
String newstr = text.replace("{","");
```

then find how many characters were replaced:

```
int newlength = newstr.length();
int replacedNumber = length - newlength;
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP's question why the last character is skipped: Note that you increment your `count2` variable in every loop, but sometimes, you shorten the string by one. In the moment you shorten the string, you should also decrement `count2` to have the loop working, otherwise, you will skip some characters.

In general, if you modify either the count (`count2`) or the condition (`newText`) variable within a `for` loop, you should carefully think about what you are doing. It is not necessarily wrong, but it makes things usually much more complex to understand.

Comment: Another way to fix the behaviour is to loop from string end to string beginning, deleting a character doesn't influence your loop counter in this case.